# Qt QLocale time format differs for default/system local and onw local for same country and language

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem when I manually set the QLocale.

For example, the following code prints:

```
auto defaultLocale = QLocale();
auto de_DE = QLocale("de_DE");

qDebug() << defaultLocale.name() << defaultLocale.country() << defaultLocale.timeFormat();
qDebug() << de_DE.name() << de_DE.country() << de_DE.timeFormat();
```

> "de_DE" QLocale::Germany "HH:mm:ss"
> "de_DE" QLocale::Germany "HH:mm:ss **t**"

Why does the time format change when I manually create the QLocale instead of using the default one?

Is there a way to change the timeFormat of the manually created QLocale?

I'm using QT 5.15.

I would expect that the timeFormat is the same.

Comment: What OS are you on and how did you configure your locale for your user or system?

Comment: @Botje The OS is Windows 10. It is freshly installed with German language. No manual change. But the same happens on an English system.